# Django automated API calls

Tags: python, django, rest

Actually I am starting off to make **automated API calls** in **django** so that third party app can use it.

I want to know about any library that could help in achieving my
objectives. I want to use [restful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) API calls as far as i have a vague
idea.

I need suggestions to start off with.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django TastyPie](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/&ei=JmJpUIOHNcfO4QTOo4D4Bw&usg=AFQjCNFDCsVmH564zDOi0wVPCOQNvkXRaw) creates restful APIs for models in 1 line of code.

Comment: yes i have looked into it..
actually i want to provide my API to 3rd party users so taht can just make calls and get desired functionality.
what do u think is the best solution to this

Comment: tastypie should be fine for this... is there a reason you think it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: If you need to manipulate your Django models (create, change or delete them), tastypie is just fine.